# OCaml option return value and option matching

Tags: match, ocaml, option-type, ml

I want to write a function that accepts values of a custom class `myType`, and returns `myType option`. Not sure if my problem is with signature, content or return values.

For example, I've tried to write the following (it's simplified and have no real meaning):

```
let rec myFunc (t:myType) myType option =
  let t2 = myFunc t in
    match t2 with
    | None -> None
    | _ -> t
```

And I'm getting the following compilation error:

> Error: This pattern matches values of type 'a option
>          but a pattern was expected which matches values of type 'b -> 'c -> 'd

Not sure what's wrong with my syntax or where I'm misunderstanding OCaml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I only see a missing colon and `Some`:

```
let rec myFunc (t:myType): myType option =
    let t2 = myFunc t in
    match t2 with
    | None -> None
    | _ -> Some t
```

Slightly streamlined version:

```
let rec myFunc (t:myType): myType option =
    match myFunc t with
    | None -> None
    | _ -> Some t
```

Comment: It looks like an infinite loop to me.

Comment: Of course it is. OP says: (it's simplified and have no real meaning)